# How to make pimcre menu open items in _blank window using hardlink

Tags: hardlink, pimcore

I have Pimcore cms which has a menu who consist of many link. Those links is created using hardlink. I want to create such link to some page with link property target="_blank". How can I do this? Can it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom property for link target and render this into the template, while you output the menu.

Comment: I never thought that it will be so hard to create some simple target parameter to a link :( This is weird.